# Button clicked in Site.Master page fires click event in content page.

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, mouseclick-event

I'm trying to have a button that's clicked in the Site.Master page to fire a click event in the content page.

I understand that the Master-page actually turns into a child class on compilation.

I've tried several different solutions after a few hours of googling with no result in site.

Here is the current solution I have applied:

```
PageLoad()
{
Button btn = this.Master.FindControl("lbtnMaintenance") as Button;
            btn.Click += new System.EventHandler(MasterlbtnMaintenance);
  }


 private void MasterlbtnMaintenance(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MaintenanceHomeScreen(true);
        }
```

Comment: I think what you need is nested master-pages approach here.

Comment: where is your button btn on master page or on content page

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar It's on my Master Page

Comment: @Rex I dont believe that's the case here, since masterpages ultimately act as user controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Created an Interface on .aspx page:
public interface ICommandable
{
    void LblMaintenanceClick(object argument, EventArgs e);
    } 

public partial class Default : Page, ICommandable
{
 public void LblMaintenanceClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {

             }
}

    // On master page: 
      public void lbtnMaintenance_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
                 {
                        if (Page is ICommandable)
                    {
                         (Page as ICommandable).LblMaintenanceClick(sender, e);
                     }
                 else
                     throw new NotImplementedException("u NO WURK");

            }
```